# remove the carriage return from CSV rows

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to process a CSV file where some of the rows ends with carriage return using python. I would like to concatenate the row that ends with carriage return with the row next to it.

Example:

```
889163812,V21,CO1045652905,Primary,,"Comp","KRIGSTIN 
& XU","LLP",01-JAN-53
```

What I would like to have is

```
889163812,V21,CO1045652905,Primary,,"Comp","KRIGSTIN & XU","LLP",01-JAN-53
```

My sample code reading the file

```
with open('/inputfile.csv', encoding="utf-8", newline='') as csvfile:
reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
```

Any pointers how to achieve this?

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1):

I would skip the csv library and just read it in if you don't need delimited data:

```
with open('/inputfile.csv', encoding="utf-8") as f:
    data= f.read().splitlines()
    my_string= "".join(data)
```

Comment: Thanks Mark.
I would like to keep the structure file as a CSV. Essentially, after concatenating the rows, I would like to process file further for data transformation tasks.

Any advice is highly appreciated? Thanks

Comment: It depends on what processing you want to do.  If you want to tokenize each word in a line, then split the lines with str.split(',').  When you want to save again, just make sure you use the .csv extension.  All extensions do, really, is tell you OS what program to use to open a file.  You could have no extension on the file and the contents probably wouldn't change (don't quote me on that).